# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'landon_app'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently following a laravel/mysql tutorial on lynda and followed the following steps to create a database and connect it to my laravel framework.

The following steps helped name my database, change my user name, and password (in which it is no longer user:root, password:root):

```
1. CREATE DATABASE landon_app;
2. CREATE USER 'landon_app'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'landon_app';
3. GRANT ALL ON landon_app.* TO 'landon_app'@'localhost';
```

after doing so, I am able to run this on the command line: mysql -u -landon_app -plandon_app

and mysql is up and running.

BUT the problem is, after I create my migrations and set up the table architecture and everything, I get an error saying

```
     SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'landon_app'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_sc  
  hema = landon_app and table_name = migrations)

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'landon_app'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I've already updated my .env file also:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=landon_app
DB_USERNAME=landon_app
DB_PASSWORD=landon_app
```

Why is that and has anyone else run into something similar? I figured since the command line `mysql -u -landon_app -plandon_app` is working, there shouldn't be a problem with `php artisan migrate`

Anything will help!

Thanks!

EDIT: config/database.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: If that command works, then the user doesn't have a password set, so you should set DB_PASSWORD to blank

Comment: So, you _can_ run the query from the CLI?

Comment: @Derek I just set the DB_PASSWORD to blank and I still get the same error :(

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey: mysql -u -landon_app -plandon_app works, php artisan migrate does not

Comment: Yes, you say "works", but THIS specific line, in CLI:  "select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = landon_app and table_name = migrations"?  And you get results in CLI?

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey: Sorry, I misunderstood. What I mean by "works" is that when i run the command mysql -u -landon_app -plandon_app, the terminal would give access to mysql. but when I run php artisan migrations, the error would appear.

Comment: Can you paste your `config/database.php` file in a gist and share it with us?

Comment: I had this problem before, please try two things. First, replace `localhost` by `127.0.0.1` in the env file. Secondly, hardcode the values at `config/database.php`, do not use `env()`.

Comment: @user2094178 I hardcoded the values into the mysql section in the database.php file but I still get the same error.

Comment: You should avoid putting database details anywhere but your .env file for security reasons. Also, whenever you change anything in your .env file you need to run: 

    php artisan config:cache

This will clear and cache the new details in your .env. Does your MySQL actually have a password, try changing username to root and password to null. Do you use a graphic interface for your database such as navicat?

Answer (score 1):

Probably PHP is using a TCP connection and not a socket connection. In this case, you need permission for `127.0.0.1`.

```
1. CREATE USER 'landon_app'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'landon_app';
2. GRANT ALL ON landon_app.* TO 'landon_app'@'127.0.0.1';
```

Or you need to specify the `DB_SOCKET` to define your socket. You can get this information using the command below:

```
mysql > show variables like '%socket%';
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name                           | Value                        |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| performance_schema_max_socket_classes   | 10                           |
| performance_schema_max_socket_instances | -1                           |
| socket                                  | **/tmp/mysql_sandbox45007.sock** |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Here is an example:

```
 mysql -uroot -pmsandbox -S /tmp/mysql_sandbox45007.sock
```

And your `.env`:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=landon_app
DB_USERNAME=landon_app
DB_PASSWORD=landon_app
DB_SOCKET=<socket>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to add privileges to `information_schema` database:

```
GRANT ALL ON `information_schema`.* TO 'landon_app'@'localhost';
```

(Followed by: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` to apply changes.)

Comment: I went back and added privileges to information schema and then the FLUSH PRIVILEGES and i got the following error:

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the RELOAD privilege(s) for this operation